# Show an attachment in customer portal

Tags: oracle, rightnow-crm

In my widget, I want to display attachment image on to customer portal page. I have created a custom object called 'Events'.All events must have images. So I stored images as attachments. Now we want to display attachment image as thumbnail So I need URL of attachment. I don't how to get URL of attachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File attachments aren't exposed to the web server, so you cannot simply reference a path to serve the image based on your object id.  You could implement an API call from the controller/widget that queries for the file attachment and then inserts the image into the DOM.  This could be done server-side with CPHP; use the [FileAttachment](http://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/february2017/Connect_PHP/Content/Connect%20for%20PHP%20API/RightNow%20Connect%20Object%20Model/Core/FileAttachment.html) sub-object on your custom object to collect the base64 encoded data of the image and then output it in the DOM.  Alternatively, you could call the [REST API](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/servicecs_gs/CXSVC/Chunk1778098949.html#aa1168635) through JavaScript and update the DOM during/after page load to get the image.